# A measure which is not continuous from above

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega= \mathbb{N}$, $F = P(\Omega)$, and $A_n = \{j \mid j \in\mathbb{N}, j \geq n\}$, $n \in\mathbb{N}$. Let
$\mu$ be the counting measure on $(\Omega,F)$, so that $\mu(A) = |A|$. I need to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} μ(A_n) \neq
\mu\bigg(\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_n\bigg).$$

Now, for a fixed $n$, $μ(A_n)$ cannot be finite, because it is equal to $|N|-|{1,2\dots,n}|$ and then $N$ will be a finite set. So, left hand side of the identity is $\infty$. Now in the right hand side of the identity the set $\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_n$ is the set of all natural numbers which are greater than all the natural numbers. Naturally, this set is null set. So, $\mu$ applied on it becomes zero. So, they are unequal.

The reason I posted this question is to find why is this happening. For a measure like probability this does not happen. I guess the reason is probability is a finite measure whereas here our measures are infinite. Want to know more intuition on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute $\mu(A_n)$ what you get? Find $\cap_{n\ge 1} A_n$ what you get?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For a fixed $n$, how many elements are in $A_n$? What elements are in
$$
\bigcap_{n\geq 1}A_n
$$
i.e. how many natural numbers are greater than $n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

- $μ(A_n)=\infty$ is the number of natural numbers $\ge n$, so the limit as $n\to \infty$ is $\infty$.
- $\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_n=\emptyset$ because there are no elements $x\in\Omega$ that belong to all $A_n$, thus $μ(\bigcap_{n\geq 1} A_n)=μ(\emptyset)=0$.