# Counterexample to upper continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a set $X$ and let $\mu:M\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a finitely additive set function.  I'm trying to decide if it's automatically true that for all ascending chains $\{A_k\}$ in $M$:

$$\mu\big(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\big)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_k)$$

I mean we clearly have $\mu\big(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_k\big)=\mu(A_n)$.  These are two identical sequences of real numbers, how can their limits be different? Thus I can see no way for the above not to be true, it doesn't even require finite additivity.  But the above statement along with finite additivity implies that $\mu$ is a measure, which would then force one to conclude that finite additivity implies countable additivity, which I don't think is supposed to be true; although the only counterexample to this I could find was one which involved ultrafilters, and don't be bringin' those ultrafilters round here boy, or we're gonna have strong words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^n A_k) = \mu(A_n)$  because $\cup_{k=1}^n A_k = A_n$.  This is true for any set function $\mu$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307865/a-measure-which-is-not-continuous-from-above) features a countably additive set-function into $[0, \infty]$ which is not upper continuous.  Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, 2^\mathbb{N},\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure.  Let $A_n = \{k \in \mathbb{N}: k \geq n\}$.  Then $\bigcap_{1}^\infty A_n = \emptyset$ so that $\mu(\bigcap_1^\infty A_n) = 0$ while $\mu(A_n) = \infty$ for any $n$.

Comment: i think you want intersections instead of unions yeah?

Comment: The $A_n$ are not ascending.. But I think I see what your getting at with pushing the limit through the measure function in some sense.  It's probably pretty difficult to construct one that satisfies all the required properties.

Comment: You are both right -- my answer is about continuity from above, not from below.  Apologies.